# Auto-unchecking a box after letting a user trigger a script by checking that box only works for creator, not user?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

As an admin in Google Workspace, I've made a script to let teachers create an ordering list. The script duplicates a hidden sheet and asks the user for the school name and their own name. This is filled into the duplicated sheet and the protection scheme of the sheet is also copied.

To prevent teachers to have to go thru the procedure of allowing the script te run, I've added an `onEdit` function: a teacher triggers the script by checking a "I want to order" checkmark.
To let other teachers use the same checkmark to create an ordering sheet, I've added code that unchecks the checkmark right after the scripts runs.

Now the strange part: everything works just fine, except the unchecking part... That is to say: if I trigger the script, the checkmark is unchecked. But if a teachers with whom I shared the sheet triggers the script, the checkmark is NOT unchecked afterwards.

The code is as follows:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Instructie');
  var range = e.range;

  // Controleer of de bewerking plaatsvond in het tabblad 'Instructie' en of de tekst 'Ik wil bestellen' is aangevinkt
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Instructie' && range.getValue() == true && range.getA1Notation() == 'J8') {
    NieuweBestellijst();

    // Set box in J8 and J10 FALSE again. But does only work for creator/owner of sheet, not other editors.
    sheet.getRange('J8').setValue(false);
  }
}
```

For now, I've added an `onOpen` trigger with the same code:

```js
    sheet.getRange('J8').setValue(false);
```

...and that works fine for everybody, which makes it even stranger... Hope someone can shine some light here! ChatGPT came up with inventive solutions, but none worked...

UPDATE:
I later stumbled on the same issue, but a different circumstance. And indeed noticed, like @Saddles, that simplifying the code (a little) made the problem disappear. So I changed the code as follows:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Instructie');
  var range = e.range;

  if (sheet.getName() == 'Instructie' && range.getValue() == true && (range.getA1Notation() == 'J8' || range.getA1Notation() == 'J10')) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == 'J8') {
      range.setValue(false);      
      NieuweBestellijst();
    }
  }
}
```

And now it works! I don't know why, but it appears to me that somehow the sheet needs to be in focus for at least a few milliseconds to let the script be able to edit the sheet, before the focus changes to the newly made sheet (called "Bestellijst").
When I'm logged in as owner, there's no need for that, met being logged in as another person apparently there is. Maybe some kind of hack protection?

Oh, by the way, the change from `sheet.getRange('J8').setValue(false);` to `range.setValue(false);` did not make a difference. I changed that later because the latter looks nicer.

Comment: I replicated the issue without the `NieuweBestellijst()` function, and unchecking works as expected for other users. My theory is that the function exceeds the 30-second limit, preventing the checkbox from being unchecked. According to [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), `They cannot run for longer than 30 seconds.` If this is not the cause, I recommend that you submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on.

Comment: Thanks you so much for replying and taking the time to look into it @Saddles! I was just returning because I could fix it, and wanted to explain how I did it (short answer: I've got no idea). It could very wel be the reason you explain, but my code is short and there seems to be no loops. The script runs in just a few seconds.